# how to change theme property (eg: textColorAnswe) using android java code

Tags: java, android

for example i have a style

```
<style name="apptheme.home">
   <item name="textColorAnswer"> @Color/blue </item>
   <item name="layoutColorAnswer"> @Color/red </item>
</style>
```

how to change the color of textColorAnswer and layoutColorAnswer with android java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color values in styles file are immutable.

They can only be changed manually while developing and not during the runtime of the application.

If you want to change the theme of the application you need to create different styles with different names.

Eg.

```
<style name="RedTheme">
    <item name="textColorAnswer"> @Color/blue </item>
    <item name="layoutColorAnswer"> @Color/red </item>
</style>

<style name="BlueTheme">
    <item name="textColorAnswer"> @Color/red </item>
    <item name="layoutColorAnswer"> @Color/blue </item>
</style>
```

After defining all the styles then you need to call these themes using

setTheme(R.style.BlueTheme);

OR

getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.RedTheme, true);

These methods should be called before the

setContentView(R.layout.main);

OR

//for data binding layouts

binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main);

> setTheme() and getTheme() method will only work before setting the
> View of the layout else the app will crash.

Comment: thank you, i want to change the whole font of the screen, do you have any solution